# What's the best practice for performing updates to aws redshift database using aws boto3 redshift-data api service?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, boto3

Due to limited access and tooling, I am stuck with using the redshift-data api.

Specifically, I am using boto3 to work with a redshift table. I want update columns on specific rows. But I have ran into api limitations with the boto3 [ExecuteStatement](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/redshift-data/client/execute_statement.html) operation.  I can't send a ExecuteStatement with an update query over 100kB. I get the following exception:

```
Failed to query redshift for list of processed buckets, An error 
occurred (ValidationException) when calling the ExecuteStatement 
operation: Cannot process query string larger than 100kB
```

Am I using the best api call for the task at hand? Or may I need to adjust the updates to be done in batches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From AWS Support

> "ValidationException: An error occurred (ValidationException) when
> calling the ExecuteStatement operation: Cannot process query string
> larger than 100kB"
>
> As you correctly mention, the reason you are receiving this error is
> that while using Amazon Redshift Data API there is a limit of maximum
> query statement which is 100KB [1]. This is by design a hard limit for
> the Query size in RedShift Data API which cannot be increased.
>
> The recommendation to overcome these limitations is to reframe your
> query so that it obeys the limitations of Redshift Data API. One
> useful approach could be the use of stored procedures and inserting
> the query inside the procedure to execute or as you already mention,
> adjust the updates to be done in batches.
>
> However, if this is not a possible solution for you, another
> workaround could be the use JDBC/ODBC client connection to submit your
> query. Kindly note that even with this option, we have to keep in mind
> that the maximum size for a single Amazon Redshift SQL statement is 16
> MB [2].
>
> [1] Data api considerations
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/data-api.html#data-api-calling-considerations
>
> [2] The maximum size for a single Amazon Redshift SQL statement
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-sql.html

Answer (score 0):

Having a SQL statement over 100K implies that you are passing the data for the update in the SQL statement itself.  This is a bad practice in Redshift as this data is being processed through the leader node, compiled into the executable code for the compute nodes, and then sent to the compute nodes.  This overloads the leader node and can slow the cluster down considerably.

The data should be loaded directly to the compute nodes from S3 using the COPY command.  This will require that your code creates an (several) S3 objects for the update data and then issue the SQL RS data API calls that uses this data to update the table.

Comment: I found that there are Amazon Redshift SQL COPY and UNLOAD commands.  "You can use AWS Glue for Spark to read from and write to tables in Amazon Redshift databases. When connecting to Amazon Redshift databases, AWS Glue moves data through Amazon S3 to achieve maximum throughput, using the Amazon Redshift **SQL COPY** and UNLOAD commands. In AWS Glue 4+, you can use the Redshift integration for Apache Spark to read and write with optimizations and features specific to ..."  Is the COPY command you are referring to?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html. The command doesn't look like a means to updating existing records, but for loading data.

Comment: Correct.  The assumption I'm working with is that you are getting SQL statements this large due to providing the data through the SQL statement itself.  INSERT INTO <table> VALUES (X, Y, Z), (A, B, C), ... .  This is a bad pattern and leads to very large statements.  You should load the data you want to use to update your table through a COPY command and then apply this data to the table with a much smaller SQL statement.  This is the best practice pattern.  If you are making a statement of 100k chars w/o data being present please let us know.